# How do I get a value when click on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my html code

```
<ul id="pageList">
    <li><a>1</a></li>
    <li><a>2</a></li>
    <li><a>3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Below is my js code

```
  $('#pageList').on('click', 'a', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  })
```

When I click on each a tag, how to get value of a tag?

Comment: `a` tags don't have `val()`, they have `text()` or `html()`, so change it to `console.log($(this).html());` and you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `.text()`

```
$('#pageList').on('click', 'a', function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure JavaScript :

```
var li = document.getElementById('pageList').getElementsByTagName('li'); // or 'a'
for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++)
{
    li[i].addEventListener('click', function()
    {
        console.log(this.innerHTML); //Will log : <a>1</a> for example
    }
}
```